# OpenSSL hanging when trying to encrypt

Tags: openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I am hoping there is someone here who knows something about OpenSSL. I am completely new to OpenSSL and I'm trying to implement it to encrypt dynamically generated PayPal buttons for a web store. I have a PHP script that does this, however it was not working, so I decided to try to run the command in command prompt and realized that it is hanging when I try to encrypt.

I have generated a public certificate and a private key and also I have downloaded PayPal's public certificate.

This is the command I tried:

```
(openssl smime -sign -signer C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\my-pubcert.pem -inkey 
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\my-prvkey.pem -outform der -nodetach -binary 
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\DataToEncrypt.txt) | openssl smime -encrypt -des3 
-binary -outform pem C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\paypal_cert.pem
```

When I run this command I get the following message:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state -Loading 'screen' into random state -done done
```

At this point it hangs. Does anyone with any OpenSSL experience know why this is happening to me? Please keep in mind I have never used OpenSSL before so I might be overlooking something simple, which is why I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I appreciate any suggestions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `-in` in the first half of the command, which is subsequently trying to read data from standard input (and thus hanging).

The correct command line should be

```
openssl smime -sign -signer C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\my-pubcert.pem -inkey 
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\my-prvkey.pem -outform der -nodetach -binary 
-in C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\DataToEncrypt.txt | openssl smime -encrypt -des3 
-binary -outform pem C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\OpenSSLTest\paypal_cert.pem
```

Notice the addition of `-in` to line 3.

Then DataToEncrypt.txt will be correctly read as an input file.